# How to test new data in existing Naive Bayes algorithm (Python 3)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Sorry for any obvious mistakes here- I am a genuine newbie.  I split a dataset into training/test and successfully applied a Bayes algorithm with a result of 0.8888 (see code below).  I now want to apply a second dataset to this existing algorithm- same features and labels but unknown outcome.  How can I accomplish this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testdf = pd.read_csv("train_predictions.csv")

#change output settings
pd.set_option("display.width", 400)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 20)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 200)

# print data types of each column
print(testdf.dtypes)

# transform str data to numerical
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
testdf["ID"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["ID"])
testdf["THAL"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["THAL"])
print(testdf.head())

# ID is not relevant to model, HEART DZ will be our target
cols = [col for col in testdf.columns if col not in    ["ID","HEART DZ"]]
data = testdf[cols]
target = testdf["HEART DZ"]
print(data.head())

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# split dataset
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.30, random_state=10)

# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

gnb = GaussianNB()
pred = gnb.fit(data_train, target_train).predict(data_test)
print("Naive-Bayes accuracy : ",accuracy_score(target_test, pred, normalize=True))
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
testdf = pd.read_csv("train_predictions.csv")
predictdf = pd.read_csv("export_dataframe.csv")

#change output settings
pd.set_option("display.width", 400)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 20)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 200)

# print data types of each column
#print(predictdf.head())

# transform str data to numerical
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
testdf["ID"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["ID"])
testdf["THAL"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["THAL"])
predictdf["ID"] = le.fit_transform(predictdf["ID"])
predictdf["THAL"] = le.fit_transform(predictdf["THAL"])
#print(predictdf.head())

# ID is not relevant to model, HEART DZ will be our target (drop them)
cols = [col for col in testdf.columns if col not in ["ID","HEART DZ"]]
data = testdf[cols]
target = testdf["HEART DZ"]
pred_cols = [col for col in predictdf.columns if col not in ["ID","HEART DZ"]]
pred_data = predictdf[cols]
pred_target = predictdf["HEART DZ"]
#print(pred_data.head())

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# split dataset
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.30) #random_state=10)

# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

gnb = GaussianNB()
pred = gnb.fit(data_train, target_train).predict(data_test)
predictions = gnb.predict([predictdf])
#print("Naive-Bayes accuracy : ",accuracy_score(target_test, pred, normalize=True))
print(predictions)
```

UPDATED CODE 2

```
testdf = pd.read_csv("train_predictions.csv")
testlabelsdf = pd.read_csv("train_labels.csv")
predictdf = pd.read_csv("export_dataframe.csv")
#print(testlabelsdf.head())

# transform str to int
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
testdf["ID"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["ID"])
predictdf["ID"] = le.fit_transform(predictdf["ID"])
testdf["THAL"] = le.fit_transform(testdf["THAL"])
predictdf["THAL"] = le.fit_transform(predictdf["THAL"])

# ID is not relevant to model, HEART DZ will be our target (drop them)
cols = [col for col in testdf.columns if col not in ["ID"]]
data = testdf[cols]
target = testlabelsdf["HEART DZ"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# split dataset
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(data, target, random_state=10) #test_size=0.30,random_state=10)

# Gaussian Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(data_train, target_train)
target_pred = gnb.predict(data_test)
ac = accuracy_score(target_test, target_pred, normalize=True)

yNew = gnb.predict(predictdf)
#print(yNew)

for i in range(len(predictdf)):
    print("Predicted: ", yNew[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

[any estimator](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L52) class in scikit-learn library contains a method called predict, and your GaussianNB is not exception so, in order to predict the label of your new data you can use .predict method as follows;

```
...your codes here
gnb = GaussianNB() #again your code
...your codes here as well
data_to_predict = ... # load your new data to predict here 
predictions = gnb.predict[data_to_predict]
print(predictions)
```

for details have look at [this documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did as you recommended and am getting an error message as follows: cannot copy sequence with size 90 to array axis with dimension 15.  I am assuming this error is coming up because the dataset I am trying to predict has 90 rows and the output of the training dataset has 15 rows.  Not sure how to correct this.  Full edited code is above:

Comment: you have to apply the same preprocessing operations (which you did to the trainig data) to the prediction data.